# What all packages do I have?

Tags: python

**OS** Windows XP SP3

**situation**

I installed three python exes on my machine.

1. Python 2.6
2. Python 2.7
3. Python EPD ENABLED (for pylab)

**problem**

I installed wxPython and in the selection I decided to install it to `Python in system registry`

I don't know to which python this package was installed.

**what I tried**

I tried writing `import wx` on all the shells and found that it was installed to EPD python.

**bigger issue**

I don't want to keep doin this each time I install a package.  So is there a command that can be used in the shell or any other way, so that I can know about all the packages installed?

**please** help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `help()` in the shell. And then in the help prompt type `modules` to see a complete list of all modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a complete list with `sys.builtin_module_names` and `pkgutil.walk_packages()`:

```
import pkgutil
import sys

print sys.builtin_module_names + [name for module_loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages()]
```

The `modules` subcommand of `help()` puts a friendlier interface on top of these results.